# Trouble using HTML Canvas with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, html5-canvas

I am trying to upload an image using HTML canvas.  The reason that I am using canvas, is because depending on the data I get back from the api, I will be super-imposing other little images over it, and this seems easier to do in canvas.

I am trying to create a new html image like this:

```
    const imgObj = new Image()
    imgObj.src = '../../pic'
    ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 200, 200)
```

When I try to use this code in vue.js (as part of a javscript function called during the "onCreate" part of the life cycle), I am told that `Image()` is not defined.

So instead I have tried this:

```
    const imgObj = document.createElement('img')
    imgObj.src = '../../pic'
    ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 20, 20)
```

As far as I understand it, this should do that same thing, but nothing renders when I do this.

If I simply insert an `<img>` into the html, the picture loads, just fine, but as I said above, I will be overlapping a bunch of smaller photos on top, and working with a bunch of images seems a lot easier to manage with canvas.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second way, you need to call `drawImage` inside `onload` function:

```
const imgObj= document.createElement('img')
imgObj.src = '../../pic'

imgObj.onload = function () {
   ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 20, 20)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  I'm also not sure if this needs to be called within `onload` because this code is being executed in vue's `created` portion of the lifecycle, which seemingly does the same as using `onload`

Also, you are using `img` two times, and `imgObj` two times, but `imgObj` is not defined.  Are all four of those instances supposed to be the same variable?

Comment: If you create a new Image, It won't be loaded by the time they are added to the canvas.

Comment: This works.  I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before.  Thanks.